# ISAPI Rewrite - allow a subdomain to only hit a specific folder

Tags: url-rewriting, isapi, isapi-rewrite

Is there a way with ISAPI v3 to allow a subdomain to only hit a specific folder, and all other requests would redirect to www? I also have some urls under this folder that need to be rewritten.  There will also be rewrite rules for valid www urls.

**Allow:**

http://myaccount.mysite.com/account/

http://myaccount.mysite.com/account/profile/

http://myaccount.mysite.com/account/profile/changeEmail.aspx

**Allow, but needs to be rewritten:**

http://myaccount.mysite.com/account/edit/123456789.aspx

**These should be redirected to www:**

http://myaccount.mysite.com/directory/

http://myaccount.mysite.com/folder1/

http://myaccount.mysite.com/folder1/folder2/
etc....

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^myaccount\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^account/edit/123456.aspx$ /otherpage [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^myaccount\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^account/.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^myaccount\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```